# C# Accord.NET elementwise addition obsolete?

Tags: c#, matrix, accord.net

When I try to do the addition between a NxD matrix and a Nx1 vector (all elements are double type) using:

```
var result = Elementwise.Add(M, v, 1);
```

Though it get right result, I got warning:

```
'Elementwise.Add(double[*,*], double[], int)' is obsolete: 'Please specify a VectorType instead of an integer for the dimension argument'
```

After google and look up the doc, I still have no idea what should I do with elementwise addition for Matrix in C#. It seems the dev will remove some of overloads in future.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you read the obsolete message ("Please specify a VectorType instead of an integer for the dimension argument") and understand what it was saying? You only seem to have one integer argument so changing it to a vector type instead seems like an obvious course of action...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `Elementwise.Add` is obsolete - it's the specific overload you're using that's obsolete. Looking at the source code, I suspect you just want:

```
var result = Elementwise.Add(M, v, VectorType.ColumnVector);
```

I believe the call you're making with `1` as the dimension value ends up effectively casting that `1` to `VectorType`, and as shown in [`Elementwise.cs`](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/f0086b852740c656f27257c2f02fa95ae376d3f8/Sources/Accord.Math.Core/Elementwise.cs#L51), the value 1 corresponds to `ColumnVector`.

Comment: You don't need to look at the source code even. The obsolete message explicitly says "Please specify a VectorType instead of an integer for the dimension argument"...

Comment: @Chris: So without looking at source code (or anything beyond what's in the question), which `VectorType` value would you have used? How would you even know what the values within `VectorType` are? How would you know whether the value passed for `dimension` as an `int` is equivalent to the corresponding value in `VectorType`? The warning message says to use `VectorType`, but that isn't enough information on its own.

Comment: Well, intellisense would tell me the available values for `VectorType` and if I am writing this code I presumably know what type of vector I have... From looking at the source you linked the `ColumnVector` value even has the help text "The vector is a column vector, meaning it should have a size equivalent to [N x 1] where N is the number of elements in the vector.". Don't get me wrong, I liked your answer (and +1ed). I just think that encouraging people to follow the instructions they are given before diving into the source code is nice! :)

Comment: @Chris: That wouldn't help me to provide the answer though. I think an answer with the exact replacement code is better than "Press space and see what comes up - hopefully the naming will be obvious."

Comment: That is a fair comment. :) And as I say, I wasn't necessarily saying its a problem, just that I personally think a mention of the message in the obsolete warning would be nice. That way next time they come across a similar obsolete message they might think to check it and solve their own problem in the future (I think all obsolete messages I have seen to date tell you what to use instead).

Comment: Thanks your guys opinion. I'll try

Comment: Thanks @DaisyShipton! And I believe it could have better phrase for the warning message. At least give an example how they gonna change. It's difficult for someone never use VectorType to know this, especially from a Python guy who just enter C#. Anyway, thanks your guys